# How to delegate Azure resources to any other user?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

How to delegate Azure resources to anyother user?

I have a subscription with resource group i would need another user to access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Go to access control (IAM) and add the user:

[image]

more info and how to do it using powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-role-assignments-group-powershell#optional-list-access-using-the-azure-portal